# Could you underline the parts of sentence contained in: "她一向忌讳家人向陌生人提及自己的隐事"?

Tags: grammar, syntax

I am quiet weak at grammar, i know some basic chinese sentence patterns like

- S P O
- S t p P O
- t S p P O
- t p S P O

wherein: S(ubject),P(redicate),O(bject),t(imephrase),p(lacephrase)

When i look upon the sentence (from nciku):
她一向忌讳家人向陌生人提及自己的隐事

i am only sure about identifying

- the subject 她
- the timephrase 一向
- the predicate 忌讳

i am very unsure about the rest of the sentence, 
could you highlight what are the parts of speech contained in this sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: I can do diagramming]

A predicate, by definition, is the whole verb phrase following the subject. You are calling verbs predicates which probably is incorrect.

Time phrase and place phrase are nothing special, they are just verb modifiers. IMO they don't belong to grammatical analysis.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the sentence should be considered as sentence with S-P phrase as object, b/c the predicate verb indicates a mental activity, 忌讳 is similar 知道、希望，认为,.... Often confused with pivotal sentence, which is is similar in construction. It would also be considered a sentence with S-P phrase as object if the verb predicate refers to sense perception like hear,see.

S1tpP1(O1), where S1=她,tp=一向,P1=忌讳, (O1)=(S2ppP2O2),S2=家人,pp(prepositional phrase)=向陌生人,P2=提及,O2=自己的隐事,O2 is composed of attributive 自己的 and noun 隐事, seems very similar to English where the object of verb dislike can be a gerund phrase, BTW the whole sentence occurs in nciku as well as iciba with translation  She always resents her family's talking about her secrets to strangers.

Comment: it seems "you" applies to both the original question
as well as the earlier answer, and therefore also
to earlier questions by the same author, using tp to denote time phrase. According to  外国人使用汉语语法:  a word or phrase modifying or restricting the predicate is called an adverbial adjunct and the word it modifies is the head word....adverbial adjunct + modified word (verb predicate). The implication seems to be that adverbial adjuncts are part of the predicate. This text also uses the term verb predicate (not verb phrase).